# Concatinate integer arrays iteratively

Tags: java, arrays

I have a methode `in2.getImagesOneDim()` which gives me an array of integers, to be more precise the pixel values of an image. Now i want to create one big array with all the pixel values of all the images. Therefore I have to call this method several times. Now I would like to concatenate the previous output to the current output until all images are read.

In some kind of pseudo code, where the + is a concatination ... :

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
  ConArray = ConArray + in2.getImagesOneDim("../images/"+i);
 }
```

How would I do this in java ?

Comment: It is just pseudo code. I see it as the total array with all the pixel values

Comment: You already know the size is gonna be 24, why not just use an array?

Comment: because the in2.getImagesOneDim method does not return 1 value, it returns an array with a variable length of pixels. Therefore it is not possible to get the exact size of the eventual array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split big problem into many smaller and You find the way:

1. Read each image into separate array
2. Compute total size
3. Join sub arrays

See example

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ImageProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new ImageReader().readImages()));
    }
}

class ImageReader {

    public int[] readImages() {
        int[][] images = readImagesInto2DArray();
        return makeOneDimensionArray(images);
    }

    private int[] makeOneDimensionArray(int[][] arrays) {
        int totalLength = computeTotalLength(arrays);
        int[] array = new int[totalLength];
        int destPos = 0;
        for (int[] subArray : arrays) {
            System.arraycopy(subArray, 0, array, destPos, subArray.length);
            destPos += subArray.length;
        }
        return array;
    }

    private int computeTotalLength(int[][] arrays) {
        int length = 0;
        for (int[] subArray : arrays) {
            length += subArray.length;
        }
        return length;
    }

    private int[][] readImagesInto2DArray() {
        int size = 24;
        int[][] result = new int[size][];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result[i] = readArray(i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int[] readArray(int index) {
        // read from file
        int[] result = new int[index];
        Arrays.fill(result, index);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: where would my method come into place ? (in2.getImagesOneDim("../images/"+i)), which returns an array of int

Comment: Use Your method instead of my "readArray" method. You could put "in2" object as a argument to method "readImages".

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int[]> pixels = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
    pixels.add(in2.getImagesOneDim("../images/"+i));
}
return pixels;
```

Now you have a list of all the data, you can get the data with `pixels.get(index);`

Comment: I need an array, not an arraylist, this gives me an array list of arrays ..., how would the conversion to an array work?

Comment: @Ojtwist Sorry, I don't think you can convert it in an array. But you can just use pixels.get(5) instead of pixels[5]. Works the same.

Comment: That is not an option in my framework, it is supposed to work on the GPU with JOCL and it does not allow arraylists

Comment: @Ojtwist I am not familiar with JOCL, but can't you send them one by one?

Comment: That would defy the purpose of running it on a GPU or generally parallel. I need one big array of values :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Collections#addAll` method.

```
List<Integer> allIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
    Integer[] imageIntegers = in2.getImagesOneDim("../images/"+i);
    allIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(imageIntegers));
}

return allIntegers.toArray();
```

Comment: Is it possible to work with int instead of Integer ? Because my framework does not allow for Integer just int.

Comment: Well you can convert them if you have access to the apache lang package, http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5b%5d%29

Comment: When You convert array to list, and then when You concatenate lists, and after all, when You convert list to array - JVM invokes a lot of "copy" and "resize" methods. To avoid this You should directly work on raw array